# Facebook's GraphRequestManager() undefined, but should be working?

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native

Facebook authentication works great, but when I go to make a Graph request:

```
          const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
                '/me',
                  {
                    accessToken: tokenString,
                      fields: 'email,first_name,name,last_name,picture' 
                  },
                  this._responseInfoCallback
                );

        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();

               }
```

I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined"

Using the Chrome debugger, everything appears like it should be working, and even storing GraphRequestManager as a variable has everything it needs until I call start(). Even using sample code I've found on this site fails when I call start(). Am I missing something obvious?

Here's a little more info. I'm importing with this:

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  GraphRequest,
  GraphRequestManager
} = FBSDK;
```

If I use FBGraphRequest and FBGraphRequestManager instead of above, I get errors stating that GraphReqest, etc aren't functions when I use them. Otherwise, the rest of my code looks very similar to Shivam's, but I get 'Cannot read property 'start' of undefined', so obviously the GraphRequestManager call is failing or isn't defined (which makes no sense to me).

Comment: Did anything work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the fields you wish to request are specified inside parameters:

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
        (data) => {
          let accessToken = data.accessToken
          const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
          '/me',{
                        accessToken: accessToken.toString(),
                        parameters: {
                          fields: {
                            string: 'email,first_name,name,last_name,picture'
                          }
                        }
                      },
              this._responseInfoCallback.bind(this),
            );

        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
        })
```

Ps where did you place the functions? Are they inside the class?